# mysql check whether an integer exists in a semi-colon separated string with fully matches in where clause

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

I want to check whether a integer value  exists in a semi-comma separated string in a where clause like `where  index_of('123456;123;456','45')>0` as `instr` dose but also checks the fully match of the  integer value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your data structure so you are not storing *integers* in strings and storing *multiple values* in a single column.  This is not the SQL'ish way of storing data.

But, if you are stuck with someone else's really bad design decisions, then MySQL offers the convenient [`find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
where find_in_set(@intval, replace(STRINGCOL_YUCK, ';', ',')) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved me!